# Play! Framework REST with Hypermedia (HAL+JSON)

Tags: rest, playframework, playframework-2.3, hateoas

Is there any plugin for Play! Framework (either Java or Scala) that supports easy creation of Resources that provide hypermedia metadata along with the normal JSON entity?

Something similar to Spring Data Rest / Hateoas, that enables easy link creation for json entities.

I cant find any concrete examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there aren't any plugins/modules specifically for Play. But there are quite a few for Java and Scala that you can integrate in your project. I think you might even use Spring HATEOAS with dependency injection in Play!

Take a look here: [Hypermedia APIs using HAL](https://github.com/mikekelly/hal_specification/wiki/Libraries)

A quick look at the examples, of a few of those libraries, indicate that a Play! integration should pose no problem.

Cheers!

Comment: what you mean Play! integration should pose no problem.?